# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 - get logged in user

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I cannot get the logged in user (ApplicationUser).
In MVC 5 I used this method: `ApplicationUser appUser = await new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db)).FindByIdAsync(User.GetUserId())`. In MVC 6 the `UserManager` constructor has MORE parameters.
So this method does not work, because it gives this error message: "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter".

How can I get the logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can get the `UserManager` by dependency injection, see [this code for example](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Controllers/ManageController.cs) in Identity repo. I paste it here:

```
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    public ManageController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
}
```

If you want to get it in a view, use `@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager`

Dependency injection is everywhere in MVC 6 (I think it has been renamed to ASP.NET Core MVC?)